# Using regex with a positive look-behind to split strings in python

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

To address one of the comments, my overall goal is to be understand how to implement a regular expression that will allow me to utilize word boundaries in a positive or negative look-behind, since it seems you cannot use quantifiers.

So for my specific case, I want to be able to check that the word preceding a period ('.') is not a capitalized word. Therefore, I could approach this from two separate paths in my mind:

1) Positive look-behind that the word preceding the '.' is all lowercase, however I receive the error that the positive look-behind is zero-width, therefore I cannot use the quantifier '+' like so: `(?<=[^A-Z][a-z]+)`

2) Negative look-behind that the word preceding the '.' begins with a capitalized letter, like so: `(?<![A-Z][a-z])`

I would prefer to move forward with some adaptation of option 1, since it makes more sense to me, however open to other suggestions. Would I be able to make use of word boundaries here?

I am using this to eventually split the paragraph into respective sentences, and I would like to stick with regex as opposed to using nltk. The issue mainly resides in dealing with initials or the abbreviations of first names.

CURRENT REGEX:

```
(?<=[^A-Z][a-z])\.(?=\s[A-Z]+)
```

INPUT:

```
Koehler rides the bus. Bowman was passed into the first grade; Koehler advanced to third grade. Jon. Williams walked down the road to school. Bowman decided to go fishing; Koehler did not. C. Robinson asked to go to recess, and the teacher said no.
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Koehler rides the bus.
Bowman was passed into the first grade; Koehler advanced to third grade.
Jon. Williams walked down the road to school.
Bowman decided to go fishing; Koehler did not.
C. Robinson asked to go to recess, and the teacher said no.
```

Comment: You invested one sentence to explain what is the goal and the rest of the page discussing your approaches. It might be better to focus more on describing the problem. From your description it sounds like you might be able to do it without a regex (or using a much simpler one) instead.

Comment: Mainly wanted to show that I have spent some effort attempting to solve the problem at hand. There are some more pieces to this problem that are not pertinent to this question, such as other options for splitting, however the name initials are currently giving me the most trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend `re.sub`, for your particular case. Your regex simplifies a *lot* this way, and you don't need to use a lookbehind, since there are a lot of restrictions with those (need to be fixed width and whatnot).

**Code**

```
print(re.sub(r'(\b[a-z]+\.\s*(?!$))', r'\1\n', text, re.M))
```

---

**Output**

```
Koehler rides the bus. 
Bowman was passed into the first grade; Koehler advanced to third grade. 
Jon. Williams walked down the road to school. 
Bowman decided to go fishing; Koehler did not. 
C. Robinson asked to go to recess, and the teacher said no.
```

---

**Regex Details**

```
(         # first capture group
\b        # word boundary
[a-z]+    # lower case a-z
\.        # literal period
\s*       # any other whitespace characters (added for cosmetic effect)
(?!$)     # negative lookahead - don't insert a newline when you're at the end of a sentence
)
```

This pattern is replaced by:

```
\1        # reference to the first capture group 
\n        # a newline
```

Comment: @RickAhlf Whoops. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mystr="Koehler rides the bus. Bowman was passed into the first grade; Koehler advanced to third grade. Jon. Williams walked down the road to school. Bowman decided to go fishing; Koehler did not. C. Robinson asked to go to recess, and the teacher said no."
lst=re.findall(r'.+?\b(?![A-Z])\w+\.',mystr)
```

If multiline then use the below:-

```
lst=re.findall(r'.+?(?:$|\b(?![A-Z])\w+\b\.)',mystr,re.M)
```

Both of them would produce...

```
['Koehler rides the bus.', ' Bowman was passed into the first grade; Koehler advanced', 'to third grade.', ' Jon. Williams walked down the road to school.', ' Bowman decided to go fishing; Koehler did not.', ' C. Robinson asked to go to recess, and the teacher said no.']
```

Explanation of `'.+?\b(?![A-Z])\w+\.'`

```
.+?       #As minimal of characters as possible after the end of previous match, this makes sure we have as many distinct sentences
\b        #word boundary
(?![A-Z]) #negative lookahead => don't follow \b with [A-Z] => skip capitalized words
\w+       #the whole word
\.        #followed by a dot
```

Test regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/BApHSu/1).
Test code [here](https://repl.it/LNyl).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to create a list of the sentences, here's another option:

```
# Split into sentences (last word is split off too)    
temp = re.split('( [a-z]+\.)', text)
temp = filter(bool, temp)

['Koehler rides the', ' bus.', ' Bowman was passed into the first grade; Koehler advanced to third', ' grade.', ' Jon. Williams walked down the road to', ' school.', ' Bowman decided to go fishing; Koehler did', ' not.', ' C. Robinson asked to go to recess, and the teacher said', ' no.']

# Join the pieces back together
sentences = [''.join([temp[i], temp[i + 1]]).strip() for i in range(0, len(temp), 2)]

['Koehler rides the bus.', 'Bowman was passed into the first grade; Koehler advanced to third grade.', 'Jon. Williams walked down the road to school.', 'Bowman decided to go fishing; Koehler did not.', 'C. Robinson asked to go to recess, and the teacher said no.']
```